Error when using Apps Script to Auto Submit Google Form Response from taking data from Google Sheets
So when I run this script
function autoEntry() { 

  var wrkBk = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var wrkSht= wrkBk.getSheetByName("Data");

  var formURL = "";
  var formData = "";

  var month = "";
  var consultant = ""; 
  var mrNumber = "";
  var footone = "";
  var foottwo = "";
  var footthree = "";
  var footfour = "";
  var footfive = "";
  let noOfRows = 3009;
  
  for(let i=2; i<=noOfRows; i++)
  {
    month = wrkSht.getRange("A" + i).getDisplayValue();
    consultant = wrkSht.getRange("B" + i).getDisplayValue();
    mrNumber = wrkSht.getRange("C" + i).getDisplayValue(); 
    footone = wrkSht.getRange("D" + i).getDisplayValue(); 
    foottwo = wrkSht.getRange("E" + i).getDisplayValue(); 
    footthree = wrkSht.getRange("F" + i).getDisplayValue(); 
    footfour = wrkSht.getRange("G" + i).getDisplayValue(); 
    footfive = wrkSht.getRange("H" + i).getDisplayValue(); 

   
    
    formURL = "https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSf5PM3CK9tAtRVTkkwT9C2XLKLf6Ya6juGF2RI0DVHJGFZQow/formResponse?&pageHistory=0";
    formData = "&entry.58149479="+ month + "&entry.567715086="+ consultant + "entry.388062754="+ mrNumber + "&entry.625140546="+ footone + "&entry.1837177653="+ foottwo + "&entry.1107149058="+ footthree + "&entry.1978630608="+ footfour + "&entry.510729106="+ footfive;

    var finalURL = formURL + formData
    
    var options = {
      "method": "post"
    };
  
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(finalURL, options); 
  }
}

it gives this error
Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: <link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="16x16" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/spreadsheets/... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
Form URL view : https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf5PM3CK9tAtRVTkkwT9C2XLKLf6Ya6juGF2RI0DVHJGFZQow/viewform
Google Sheet URL: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RNwnHPRPftN9oyXpD0PfaGMIfRJoO8KotDcQH-a12xw/edit?usp=sharing
Have tried the same code for a dummy form and with respective fields corrected, it works there but not for this form.
